# $Ax=0 \equiv x=0 \implies \exists A^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

> Let $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times m}, \operatorname{Rank(A)}=m$ and consider $V=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\} \subset \Bbb R^m$. Prove that $$V \,\,\text{is}\,\, L.I. \iff  AV=\{Av_1,Av_2,\dots,Av_r\} \,\,\text{is}\,\,  L.I$$

**Attempt:**

I couldn't do the $\implies$ part so I was trying to do the $\impliedby$ part.

$\alpha_1 Av_1+\alpha_2 Av_2+\dots+\alpha_r Av_r =0 \iff \alpha_i=0 \forall i=1,\dots,r.$

$\alpha_1 Av_1+\alpha_2 Av_2+\dots+\alpha_r Av_r =0\iff A(\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2+\dots+\alpha_r v_r)=0$

So if I can multiply by the inverse of $A$ this part should be done, but I don't even know if I have a square matrix.

Comment: Since rank of $A$ is $m$, you know that $n\ge m$. You also get an injective linear transformation, which allows you to define an inverse from the domain to the image under the linear map. So it's a well defined inverse if you restrict the range to the image of the map. This is the same thing as saying it's injective. Then your result does follow.

Comment: Don't think about inverses. As the previous comment suggests, the rank condition should tell you that $Ax=0 \implies x=0$. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $A: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ the transformation associated with the matrix $A$. As the $\mathrm {rank} A = m$ then $\dim \mathcal Im (A) = m $ and $$\dim Ker (A) = m - m = 0 $$

Therefore $A$ is injective and it takes L.I. sets in L.I. sets.

Comment: Is there any way to prove this without the Rank-nullity theorem, or any interpretation of the matrix A as a linear transformation? I'm asking this because although I have studied those matters, my class haven't and so we can't use things like  that.

Comment: What can you use, because you just took all the linear algebra now.

Comment: Hmm can't I say that $\alpha_i=0 \implies \sum \alpha_i v_i=0$ and as $\alpha_i=0$ is equivalent to $\sum A(\alpha_i v_i)=0$,  $\sum A(\alpha_i v_i)=0 \implies \sum \alpha_i v_i=0$?